# How can I get the sorted document on MongoDB [mongoos] best on the where clause that matches the child object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Basically, I am trying to sort the documents best on the pattern match. My current documents looks like

```
{name: "Name2", likes: ["Apple","Cat"]}
{name: "Name1", likes: ["Apple","Ball"]}
{name: "Name3", likes: ["Moon","Light"]}
```

I want to find and order the documents based on the matches on likes. If I pass `{likes: ["Apple","Ball"]}` I want to get the documents in following order:

```
{name: "Name1", likes: ["Apple","Ball"]}
{name: "Name2", likes: ["Apple","Cat"]}
{name: "Name3", likes: ["Moon","Light"]}
```

If this can be achieved in Javascript, I would like to see how too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is assigning a "weight" to the number of matches and sorting by that. The best bet for the "exact" thing you are asking is using the aggregation framework:

```
var test = ["Apple", "Ball"];

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "score": {
      "$size": {
        "$setIntersection": [ test, "$likes" ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
])
```

Which would give you a result like this:

```
{ "name" : "Name1", "likes" : [ "Apple", "Ball" ], "score" : 2 }
{ "name" : "Name2", "likes" : [ "Apple", "Cat" ], "score" : 1 }
{ "name" : "Name3", "likes" : [ "Moon", "Light" ], "score" : 0 }
```

In short the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is a way of projecting a "new field" into the document, you can alternately use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or similar stages for this type of operation.

The `"score"` field added to the document is composed by using the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) aggregation operator to compare your source array `["Apple", "Ball"]` with the array present in the `$likes` property of the document. You use the `$` in here to refer to the "value" of that field.

The result from [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) is an "array" ( or "set" ) containing the items which matched the array given in the first argument to the one in the second argument. All we really want here is the overall "length" of that resulting "set" using the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to provide a `"score"` value indicating the number of matches.

With this new property added to the document you then use [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and use the `"score"` value in "descending" order as specified by the negative `-1` sort direction.

---

The alternate approach would generally be that with the exception of specific cases, most real world searches would not be interested at all in the document with no matches and no score at all.

In this case it would likely be far more practical and efficient to use a ["text search"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) instead.

First you would create the "text index" on the document properties you which to search on:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "likes": "text" });
```

Then you simply supply the values as a space delimited list:

```
var test = ["Apple", "Ball"];

var search = test.join(" ");    // Makes the string "Apple Ball"

db.collection.find(
  { "$text": { "$search": search } },
  { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }
).sort( { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } )
```

Which would return results like:

```
{ "name" : "Name1", "likes" : [ "Apple", "Ball" ], "score" : 2.1 }
{ "name" : "Name2", "likes" : [ "Apple", "Cat" ], "score" : 1 }
```

So you would never be including documents with no relevance match to the terms given at all but the results are far much more efficient and considerably faster at higher workloads. Note also that the operation "inherently" makes usage of an "index", which is something a calculated process using the aggregation framework cannot do.

Those are basically your approaches for sorting on the server. Aggregation pipelines are powerful and you can do many things, but the cost is generally a drop in performance over what the native query operators and indexes can actually do for you.